# Using an Arraylist in the constructor

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list of stock as a class and then a class of stores with the constructor shown below. The stores has an array list which links to the stock class.

How would I access the array list for a certain store?

E.G. If I pick the store argos I want all the stock that it has in it. Each store has its own stock

```
    public Store(int storeId, String name, String location){
      this.storeId = storeId;
     this.name = name;
     this.location = location;
      items = new ArrayList<Stock>();
     }
```

Comment: A private local variable with a getter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each `Store` has it's own list of `Stock` items, then this will have to be an **attribute**, or a **private instance variable**, of the class Stock. The items of the Store can then be accessed using a getter, eg.

```
public class Store {
    private List<Stock> items;

    public Store(List<Stock> items){
        this.items = items;
    }

    public List<Stock> getStock(){ 
        // get stock for this Store object. 
        return this.items;
    } 
    public void addStock(Stock stock){
        this.getStock().add(stock);
    }
}
```

Then, you can access the items for an instance of Store using the getter for Stock items.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* provide safe access this way, but it'd be better encapsulation if you didn't give users the keys to the store and return the stock list.

```
public class Store {
    private List<Stock> stock;

    public Store(List<Stock> stock) {
        this.stock = ((stock == null) ? new ArrayList<Stock>() : new ArrayList<Stock>(stock));
    }

   public List<Stock> getStock() {
       return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.stock);
   }
}
```

Comment: I like blackpanther's answer the best.  His "addStock" is the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I would advise using a HashMap. Have each Store as the key, or store ID, and then have the list of Stock as the value. This would allow you to simply do:

```
Map storeMap = new HashMap<String, List<Stock>();
items = storeMap.get(key);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Store {
    private List<Stock> items;

    public Store(int storeId, String name, String location){
        this.storeId = storeId;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        items = new ArrayList<Stock>();
    }

    public List<Stock> getAllStock(){
        return this.items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities to set the list to the `Store` object and with a `getter` you can `return` the list back.

```
public Store(int storeId, String name, String location,ArrayList<Stock> list){
    this.storeId = storeId;
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.items = new ArrayList<Stock>();  //or any possibility to set list
}

public ArrayList<Stock> getListOfStock(){
    return this.items;
}
```